# Json parsing error: Unterminated object at character 275 of

Tags: android, json

my code already get data(jsonstr) from website but can't make it to JSONObject and it make error Json parsing error: Unterminated object at character 2755

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Destinasi");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String nim = c.getString("nama_destinasi");
                        String name = c.getString("alamat_destinasi");
                        String alamat= c.getString("deskripsi_destinasi");
```

and this link that i try to parse
https://ombajuom.000webhostapp.com/json_destinasi.php/Destinasi

please help me and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a misplaced **`]`** and **`}`** in JSON String. The String it returns **NOW** is as follows

```
{
   "Destinasi": [
      {
         "nomor_id": "1",
         "nama_destinasi": "Ravi Tamada",
         "alamat_destinasi": "Ciledug",
         "deskripsi_destinasi": "WAhhh",
         "rating_destinasi": "3"
      ]
   }
}
```

But it should be as below to make it a valid JSON.

```
{
   "Destinasi": [
      {
         "nomor_id": "1",
         "nama_destinasi": "Ravi Tamada",
         "alamat_destinasi": "Ciledug",
         "deskripsi_destinasi": "WAhhh",
         "rating_destinasi": "3"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web service you shared is not a valid JSON format, to validate your response you can use jsonlint.com,

Thanks